# multi-thread flash

Tags: multithreading, flash, actionscript

I want to do multithreading! I want to make a timer with play/pause/stop buttoms
and when user pressed the play button, a timer starts counting.
I want to do the counting process, while this, another operation should do,
because with this timer user wants to measure sth that is going on, somwhere else in the scene
anyway, I want to to sth, and user measure how long it takes!!!
I'm newbie to flash, but as far as I know the solution is multithreading!
or is there any timer or sth like that that it can measure time, without causing the program to hang!
I'm working with as2 , but if as3 is the only way, it's fine!
tnx

Comment: Just a note, that Flash player 11.4 (released this week) now supports a true multi-threading technique they call 'actionscript workers'.  http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/08/flash-player-11-4-and-air-3-4.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash player 11.4 offers multi-threading of sorts with the new concurency (actionscript workers) features.  Read about it here:  http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/08/flash-player-11-4-and-air-3-4.html

Flash 11.3 and under don't offer multithreading. Your question though doesn't especially require multithreading though. The flash.utils.Timer class and flash.utils.setTimeout() are asynchronous and don't hang your code stack.

I would recommend looking at these classes on the adobe docs.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout()

To address your question in the comments:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000); //fire every second, make this number smaller to have it update faster
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateLabel);

var timeStamp:int;
function startTimer():void {
    timeStamp = getTimer();
    timer.reset();
    timer.start();
}

function updateLabel(e:Event):void {
    var timePassedSoFar:int = getTimer() - timeStamp;
    //update your label to show how much time has passed (it's in milliseconds)
}
```

If you only want seconds, you could also just use the timer.currentCount property (instead of getTimer()) which tells you how many times the timer has fired, which in the example above is the amount of seconds elapsed as it fires once per second.

Comment: if I want to show the seconds on the screen, what should I do?
does this timer class have the ability to do it?

Comment: if you want to show time elapsed, you can use the getTimer() function. if you want to show current time (like a clock) use the Date() object.  I'll put some sample code in my answer.

Comment: excuse me , isn't any alternative to AS2? I tried, but in AS3, my buttons don't  work!! :((
isn't any as2 timer/thread or is there any easy way to fix to fix the buttons in AS3?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding that last comment, post your code